# Facebook share in widget

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-apps, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer

I have read that the Facebook sharer is deprecated, So I wanted to know how can I create a     share button in my widget that will work from any domain (not just the app domain), via the js SDK (Preferably).

For example:
I have my app registered on myserver.com
And someone downloaded my widget on hisservers.com, I want the share to work from there and post to his wall.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FB.ui [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) to prompt the user to publish a story on their feed, and specify your link in the function. Like so

```
function postLink() {
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'http://myserver.com',
      picture: 'a_picture',
      name: 'My Server',
      description: 'Sharing MyServer from HisServer.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      console.log(response['post_id']);
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
```

Of course you'll have to also include the [proper initialization](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) for the JS SDK.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the [Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) plugin

Comment: I need to implement it via js (@avist)

Comment: That is JS! You can call the `postLink()` function, after initializing the JS SDK (see link in answer), and it will open a popup. [Example](http://www.fbrell.com/fb.ui/feed). `<a href="#share" onclick="postLink(); return false();">Share this app</a>`

Comment: Sorry, for some wired reason I didn't notice your code... thanks I have found that too!

Comment: But I can't use this code from different domains... what should I do? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286881/facebook-using-code-from-different-domains)

Answer (score 1):

```
function postLink() {
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'http://myserver.com',
      picture: 'a_picture',
      name: 'My Server',
      description: 'Sharing MyServer from HisServer.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      console.log(response['post_id']);
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
```

Comment: Format your code before posting. Also an explanation on the code would help.